# Cant call release in XCode 4.5?

Tags: objective-c

I need some help , I am a beginner in objective-c , I tried to program my first class 
but unfortunately it did not work . here is my Code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Fraction :NSObject{
    int numerator ;
    int demoniratoe ;
}
-(void) print;
-(void) setnumerator: (int) n;
-(void) setdemoniratoe: (int) b;

@end

@implementation Fraction
-(void) print
{
    NSLog(@"%i/%i",numerator,demoniratoe);
}
-(void) setnumerator: (int) n{
    numerator = n;
}
-(void) setdemoniratoe: (int) b{
    demoniratoe = b;
}

@end
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    Fraction *myfraction;
    myfraction = [Fraction alloc];
    myfraction = [Fraction init];

    [myfraction setnumerator:1];
    [myfraction setdemoniratoe:3];

    NSLog(@"The value of Fraction is :");
    [myfraction print];
    [myfraction release];

}
    return 0;
}
```

the error message was on [myfraction release] the release is unavailable
I use XCode version 4.5

Comment: Also, this question is not quite related to Xcode. If you were using vi and make to write your apps, the compiler would still throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

Since newer versions of Xcode assume you use automatic reference counting (ARC), they set up the compiler to use it, so then the compiler complains about you trying to manually manage the memory.

The solution: either turn off ARC (**I advise you as a beginner to do this,** since you should really learn how manual memory management (MRC) works!) or convert your code to ARC-compatible, i. e. remove all `retain`, `release` and `autorelease` messages (and make a few more changes; you can read about them by googling `converting Objective-C code to ARC`). You can also use Xcode to transform your MRC-compatible project to an ARC-compatible one. General official docs about ARC can be found on [Apple Developer.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

To turn off ARC, you can go to your project in Xcode, then in Build Settings, then use the search bar to search for "Automatic" and turn off the "Automatic Reference Counting" cell.

Later when you have deep knowledge about MRC, you can (and are encouraged to) switch to and learn ARC.

Comment: Yeah to this one too -- though it says the opposite thing.  Even though ARC is the Wave of the Future, it depends to a significant degree on non-ARC concepts which are best learned by turning off ARC and coding, vs just reading about them.  It's really a tough decision...

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, and if one fails to understand memory management in C, you better not let that person even in the neighborhood of AppStore. Of course, ARC is the modern technology, and one should learn it as well, but I personally still prefer MRC. (Not to mention its more cross-platform!)

Comment: Of course, understanding memory management in C and understanding memory management in Objective-C are two rather different things.  Ideally one should understand them all, but most of the novices here seem to impatient to learn it all, so you have to kind of pick and choose what's likely to work out best for the individual.

Comment: @HotLicks If one is not patient enough to learn memory management, he should not be permitted to make an iOS app. Period.

Comment: That would cut out about 80% of those working on "the next great viral iPhone app".

Comment: @HotLicks Yeah, and that's unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Automatic reference counting (ARC), then you no longer use release, autorelease, retain, as the compiler takes care of that for you.

Comment: Yep, it sounds like ARC is enabled.  So you can (sorta) forget about retain/release/et al.  In about 2 years there won't be any non-ARC code left, so there's nothing beyond academic reasons in learning it.

Comment: @HotLicks There will. And I will write it. (Seriously, you **do need** to learn MRC.)